# How to bind a ReactiveList of view models to a ListView containing Views of the view model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, reactiveui

I have a `ParentViewModel` which contains a `ReactiveList` of `ChildViewModels`. I would like to bind it to a `ListView` which will display `ChildViews`. `ChildView` binds some text to a `Label` and a sets an `Image` resource based on a status enum:

**ParentViewModel.cs** Simple container for `ChildViewModels`

```
public class ParentViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveList<ChildViewModel> Children { get; }
        = new ReactiveList<ChildViewModel>();
}
```

**ChildViewModel.cs** Has some text and a `Status`

```
public class ChildViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public string SomeText { get; set; }

    public enum Status
    {
        Unknown,
        Known
    }

    public Status CurrentStatus { get; set; } = Status.Unknown;
}
```

**ParentView.xaml** `UserControl` which wraps a `ListView`, using `ChildView` for the data template. I made sure to add the `ViewModel="{Binding}"` on my `DataTemplate`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.UI.ParentView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.View_Models"
        xmlns:ui="clr-namespace:MyProject.UI">
    <ListView x:Name="ChildList" BorderThickness="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <!--I have also tried the following line, didn't work  -->
            <!--<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChildViewModel}">-->
                <ui:ChildView ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

**ParentView.xaml.cs** Creates a dependency property for its `ParentViewModel`, and binds the view model's `Children` to the ChildList ListView

```
public partial class ParentView : UserControl, IViewFor<ParentViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ViewModel",
            typeof(ParentViewModel),
            typeof(ParentView));

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (ParentViewModel)value; }
    }

    public ParentViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ParentViewModel )GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
            BindToViewModel(value);
        }
    }

    private void BindToViewModel(ParentViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.OneWayBind(viewModel, vm => vm.Children, v => v.ChildList.ItemsSource);
    }
}
```

**ChildView.xaml** Simple `UserControl` with an `Image` and a `Label`

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.UI.ChildView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Name="StatusIcon" Margin="2" />
        <Label Name="DisplayName" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**ChildView.xaml.cs** Binds the `ChildViewModel` and sets image data

```
public partial class ChildView : UserControl, IViewFor<ChildViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ViewModel",
            typeof(ChildViewModel),
            typeof(ChildView));

    public ChildView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = (ChildViewModel)value; }
    }

    public ChildViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (ChildViewModel )GetValue(ViewModelProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
            BindToViewModel(value);
        }
    }

    private void BindToViewModel(ChildViewModel viewModel)
    {
        viewModel
            .WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.CurrentStatus)
            .Subscribe(status =>
            {
                // set StatusIcon's image based on status
            });

        this.Bind(viewModel, vm => vm.DisplayName, v => v.SomeText);
    }
}
```

I have set breakpoints in `ChildView` to see if the ViewModel properties hit, but they never do. When I add `ChildViewModels` to `ParentVieWModel.Children`, a `ChildView` is created, but it is never bound properly. I could subscribe to `Children`'s `CollectionChanged` event and manually set the binding, but I would like to do this the proper XAML/ReactiveUI way. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to fully set up your properties in your ChildViewModel so that they raise changes in the ViewModel that your ChildView can subscribe to. See [ViewModels documentation](https://docs.reactiveui.net/en/user-guide/view-models/index.html).

```
string someText ;
public string SomeText {
    get { return someText; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref someText , value); }
}

Status currentStatus;
public Status CurrentStatus {
    get { return currentStatus; }
    set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref currentStatus, value); }
}
```

Or if one or both are readonly.

```
readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<string> someText;
public string SomeText{
    get { return someText.Value; }
}

readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<Status> currentStatus;
public Status CurrentStatus{
    get { return currentStatus.Value; }
}
```